# How do I ensure that dask doesn't read unnecessary files from disk when querying a partitioned dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dask, pyarrow, dask-dataframe

For example, say I have a parquet dataset in a directory tree, hive-style:

```
dataset/field1=A/field2=X/data.parquet
dataset/field1=A/field2=Y/data.parquet
dataset/field1=B/field2=X/data.parquet
dataset/field1=B/field2=Y/data.parquet
```

And say I define a dask dataframe like this:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = dd.read_parquet("dataset/", engine="pyarrow")
```

Here, `field1` and `field2` are partition columns in my dataframe.

My question: how do I make sure dask only reads one parquet file if I do `df.query("field1 == 'A' and field2 == 'X'")`? (i.e., only read `dataset/field1=A/field2=X/data.parquet`)

Relatedly, is there a way of knowing which files dask is opening and reading? Maybe from a logger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality is supported by `pyarrow` when using filters at read time (not as `.query` method):

```py
from dask.dataframe import read_parquet
from dask.datasets import timeseries

df = timeseries(end="2000-01-03", seed=0).reset_index()
df["date"] = df["timestamp"].dt.date.astype("str")
df.to_parquet("test.pqt", partition_on=["id", "date"])
rare_id = df["id"].value_counts().compute().tail(1).index.values[0]

ddf = read_parquet("test.pqt", filters=[[("id", "==", rare_id)]], engine="pyarrow")
print(ddf.npartitions)  # 1
```

Edit: the snippet above works with `dask=2022.1.0`, but not `dask=2022.6.1`, for details check [this GH issue](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/9246).

Comment: Ah ok thanks! Just to clarify, is this the *only* way to prevent the unnecessary reads? For example, would implementing it like `ddf[ddf["field1"] == "A"]` still read all files?

Comment: Also, do you know if dask or pyarrow offer some way of showing when they're reading files? I think I've tried setting their loggers to DEBUG (`logging.getLogger("dask").setLevel("DEBUG")`) but I don't think this told me anything

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think `ddf[ddf["field1"] == "A"]` would read all the files. What I am confident about is that `dask` will skip reading specific files if there is a specific index subset of interest: e.g. if `ddf` is indexed, `ddf.loc[123]` would only read the (indexed) file that contains entry `123`.

Comment: For getting info on which file is being read, I don't know of a simple way... the only option I can think of is to look into specifics of the constructed DAG (`dict(ddf.dask)`), but there might be a better way...

Comment: I just figured out how to get info on dask reading stuff - use the `gcsfs` logger. If I set `logging.getLogger("gcsfs").setLevel("DEBUG")`, then I see messages about the GET requests for various files. Furthermore I can see that, when I define a dask DataFrame, it only GETs a few bytes in a specified range, e.g. `GET: https://storage.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/MY_BUCKET/o/MY_URI?alt=media, (), {'Range': 'bytes=47361643-47427178'}`.